# Does using SuppressKeyPress in a KeyDown event corrupt MaskedTextBoxes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keydown, maskedtextbox

I'm setting `SuppressKeyPress = true` when a user presses the ENTER/RETURN key in a `MaskedTextBox` to prevent the annoying beep that is normally made.  This works great, but when I clear my form the `MaskedTextBox` no longer behaves as expected. The first character entered is a phantom character that disappears after the 2nd character is entered.

Example:

```
__.___
Set text = "0"
0_.___
User enters text
09.999
User presses ENTER
User presses Save & Next (this clears the form)
Reset text = "0"
0_.___
User enters first 9
09_.___
User enters second 9
0_.9__
```

If the user TABS out of the `MaskedTextBox` instead of pressing ENTER, this works fine (the text is entered correctly without any odd shifting.)  The only differences I can find are that I'm using `SuppressKeyPress` and that the flagState in Non-Public Members is different (2052 when I do NOT `SuppressKeyPress` and 2048 when I DO `SuppressKeyPress`.)

Is there a way to either prevent the BEEP without breaking the `MaskedTextBox` or a way to fix the `MaskedTextBox` after `SuppressKeyPress` (I've tried most if not all the methods on the `MaskedTextBox` itself: `refreshText`, `refresh`, etc...)

Here is the MaskedTextBox definition and the KeyDown method:

```
// 
// aTextBox
// 
this.aTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(130, 65);
this.aTextBox.Mask = "##.###";
this.aTextBox.Name = "aTextBox";
this.aTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
this.aTextBox.TabIndex = 3;
this.aTextBox.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.general_KeyDown);
this.aTextBox.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.validate);
```

`general_KeyDown` looks like this:

```
private void general_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro but I definitely see it in the reference source.  MaskTextBox is also looking for Keys.Enter and sets and internal flag when it sees it, a flag that affects the key handling for subsequent keystrokes.  Your code may well mess this up.

Make sure that the control doesn't see the keystroke at all by overriding OnKeyDown.  That requires inheriting your own control, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyMaskTextBox : MaskedTextBox {

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) {
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            this.Parent.GetNextControl(this, true).Select();
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Paste the code in a new class and compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox, replacing your old one.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did repro it.  The OP's code ends up inserting a space (Chr(32)) on its next keypress.  Your post saved me from posting a horribly hacky answer.  +1.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you very much.  Any downside to using SendKeys.Key("{TAB}")?  Simply doing GetNextControl is troublesome because some of the controls on the form are not active.

Comment: "Active" doesn't mean much.  GetNextControl deals with disabled controls.  Use what you prefer.